# How do I get the theme URL in PHP?

Tags: theme-development

I need to get the URL of my theme directory to reference an image in the theme's image/headers directory. How is this done in PHP?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This function will *return* the theme directory URL so you can use it in other functions:

```
get_bloginfo('template_directory');
```

Alternatively, this function will *echo* the theme directory URL to the browser:

```
bloginfo('template_directory');
```

So an example for an image in the themes `images/headers` folder would be:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/headers/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: NOTE: this will give you the path to the *parent* theme if you are currently using a child theme, and not the active child theme. A longer answer below explains this in more detail.

Comment: You can simply use `get_template_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 32):

What *@EAMann* said, with a caveat. Eric is right about the general approach and how the functions `bloginfo()` and `get_bloginfo()` work and about how to pass the parameter `'template_directory'` to get the value you need for (most) themes.

However there is a caveat and that **caveat** is with the newer ***Child Themes***. If you are using a child theme then `'template_directory'` is probably not what you want unless you are actually trying to refer to an image that is in the parent theme directory. Instead for child themes what you probably want is to pass `stylesheet_directory` (I know, I know, the names don't tell you what they are but hey, that's just the way it is!) Borrowing somewhat from Eric's reply using `stylesheet_directory` would look like this (I shortened the example so it would not wrap):

> `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/header.jpg" />`

To illustrate the point I wrote a quick standalone file you can drop in your website's root as `test.php` and run to see what it outputs. First run with a regular theme like TwentyTen then run with a child theme:

```
<?php
/*
* test.php - Test the difference between Regular and Child Themes
*
*/

include "wp-load.php";

$bloginfo_params = array(
    'admin_email',
    'atom_url',
    'charset',
    'comments_atom_url',
    'comments_rss2_url',
    'description',
    'home',
    'html_type',
    'language',
    'name',
    'pingback_url',
    'rdf_url',
    'rss2_url',
    'rss_url',
    'siteurl',
    'stylesheet_directory',
    'stylesheet_url',
    'template_directory',
    'template_url',
    'text_direction',
    'url',
    'version',
    'wpurl',
);

echo '<table border="1">';
foreach($bloginfo_params as $param) {
    $info = get_bloginfo($param);
    echo "<tr><th>{$param}:</th><td>{$info}</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

If you notice things you might notice that there's a lot more to what you can pass to `bloginfo()` and `get_bloginfo()`; study the code and the screenshot below for ideas.

Looking at the screenshot you can see that `stylesheet_directory` returns the same thing as  `'template_directory'` for a regular theme but a different value, and probably the value you need for a child theme.

[image: The return values of get_bloginfo() with and without a Child Theme in WordPress]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100821-062658.png))</sub>

> For clarity on this screenshot,
>   `wp30.dev` is a domain that runs only
>   on my local computer. It is currently
>   an instance of WordPress 3.0.1 and it
>   is configured at `127.0.0.1` (same as
>   `localhost`) on my laptop and I use it
>   for testing ad-hoc examples like this.
>   I used [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/) as a convenience on the Mac OS X to help me set up those private non-routable `.dev` domains but anyone can do it manually by
>   editing the computer's hosts file and the 
>   ? httpd.conf file.

By the way, in case you are not familiar with ***Child Themes*** where are two other WordPress Answers that might help:

- [Making the Header on the Twenty Ten Theme Less Tall?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/462/making-the-header-on-the-twenty-ten-theme-less-tall)
- [Customizing a WordPress Theme without Changing it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290/customizing-a-wordpress-theme-without-changing-it)

Comment: Wow, great answer. I was lazy with the theme I'm working on now and didn't set up a child theme, but this will be very helpful in the future. Congratulations on that script too. Well-coded. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, nice answer! I usually use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. Should I be using plain ol' `get_stylesheet_directory()`?

Answer (score 13):

The whole structure of theme builds on top of two options - `template` (holding parent theme folder namre) and `stylesheet` (holding child theme folder namr). If there is no child theme used these are the same.

To have flexibility of filters, rather than access option directly, there are accordingly [`get_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template) and [`get_stylesheet()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet).

Now the only thing is missing is to combine those with themes folder location. This can be done with [`get_theme_root_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_root_uri) and again conveniently wrapped in [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) and [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

[`[get_]bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) with `template_directory` or `stylesheet_directory` arguments merely wraps these and there is little reason to use it like that. I'd say it is only confusing by having argument saying directory (commonly relates to local paths), but returning URLs.

Sumary:

- use `get_template_directory_uri()` to refer to **only or parent** theme
- use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to **only or child** theme

Answer (score -1):

I use this
`(dirname(get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')))`

Comment: No explanation why this is better than the other solutions?